# Do my copied documents update together?

Tags: document

In SharePoint 13, I copied one document from one folder to another. Therefore, I have to documents, one original and one copied. If I update and save either document does that update take place in the other document?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. They are now separate files.